# Microsoft Azure website creation: 'Cannot modify this site because another operation is in progress'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When publishing a new website through Visual Studio, Microsoft Azure blocks this stating I still have a pending delete operation. However, when I go to my Azure control panel, I can't find any operation still pending. The pending operation was also created about two months ago.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you recently delete a WebApp, VM or storage account attached to the same cloud service? If so Azure will make you wait until it completes unless you create a brand new cloud service.

Comment: What's the name of the site that you're trying to create which is getting blocked? You can share it directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)

Comment: 2 months ago, I deleted a VM. But that should be deleted by now.. The name of the website I'm trying to create is justcreatesomething.azurewebsites.net. It gives me the same error when using that name..

Comment: All of the sudden, I can upload it. Must have been some error with Microsoft. Closing this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A day after this error, Microsoft seems to have resolved it. I can upload my website through the default procedure now. Closing this question.

Comment: So the answer is "wait a day"?

Comment: That's what worked for me. It could be that they clear all pending operations that have been running too long in a nightly job. If it's not resolved after a day I suggest you contact support

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: Even less than a day. see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141102/azure-conflict-cannot-modify-this-site-because-another-operation-is-in-progres/35141241#35141241)

Comment: In case it helps anyone, pending operations have an expiry date, so when this happens it feels like it fixed itself but I think it's a problematic operation that ends up expiring hence fixing itself

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue myself. I think when it "fixes itself" it's actually just the pending operation timing out as an operation has a timeout date.

e.g I figured that out from this error I got

Found a duplicate certificate with itt.world available or in pending issued under serverFarmId /subscriptions/obsfuscated/resourceGroups/Default-Web-WestUS/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/DefaultServerFarm. Pending certificate operation id: xxxxx, timeout: 11/21/2021 11:54:32 AM