# Azure "Conflict: Cannot modify this site because another operation is in progress." error from Powershell command

Tags: azure

I keep getting this error on two of my four Azure webapps when trying to run my Powershell script to swap my preprod and prod slots.

The command `Start-AzureWebsite -Name $WebSiteName -Slot $SourceSlotName` results in the following error:

`Conflict: Cannot modify this site because another operation is in progress. Details: Id: b98d4832-5f6b-4bad-9c4e-470a2d0d100c, OperationName:
SwapSiteSlots, CreatedTime: 2/1/2016 9:30:54 PM, WebSystemName: websites, SubscriptionName: bd3570da-d430-485a-a83c-d4ef448b865e, WebspaceName: *******EastUSwebspace,
SiteName: *******, SlotName: preprod, ServerFarmName:
At C:\dev\...\scripts\Swap-AzureWebApp.ps1:18 char:1
+ Start-AzureWebsite -Name $WebSiteName -Slot $SourceSlotName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureWebsite], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.StartAzureWebsiteCommand`

No operation is in progress, but I did Git push to my preprod slot some 30 minutes ago...

It looks likes [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861866/microsoft-azure-website-creation-cannot-modify-this-site-because-another-opera), but it is from Powershell, not visual studio, and I'm trying to start a preprod slot, then swap it.

Answer (score 4):

It resolved itself, sigh. :/

Both of my Webapps that had errors with my scripts now swap without any error (using the same script).

I waited for about 1h...

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, did you just keep retrying it and it worked?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue when try to swap the app from staging to production in CD pipeline. As a solution deleted the staging slot and re deployed.

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to each 'slot' on the portal. (Each slow shows up as a separate app service in your resource group named "appservice-name/slot-name" format)
- on each 'slot' app service, go to deployment slots blade
- On the top, click on 'Complete Swap', then select 'Cancel Swap' in the drop down
- Click 'Cancel Swap'

Only one of these operations will succeed, and others will show the same error.

If you don't see the "Complete Swap" button, you'll just have to wait, think up to one hour.

Once succeeded, wait a few minutes before attempting to deploy/start to app service again.

Comment: This fails with the same message :(

Answer (score 0):

I used Pulumi Native to create a webapp resource. I got this error and I waited 4 days according to [dstj's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141241/3050786) answer. It didn't help. I found was is wrong in another way.

1. Go to: [Azure Support](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/%7E/overview)
2. Hit troubleshoot on a resource where you have a problem:[image]
3. Go to Configuration and Management
4. View details: [image]
5. In my case I got error: [image]
6. As it turn out, the error wasn't related to FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME per se. It was missing propety in Pulumi code: `Kind = "FunctionApp"`. At least I got some info that I've got something wrong with my code and the problem is not related with Azure service.